# Getting a java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect after update to Katalon 5.9.0

Tags: web-services, post, webdriver, katalon-studio, rocket.chat

After updating Katalon Studio from version **5.8.7** to **5.9.0** (and **5.9.1**), when sending a POST request (Rocket chat), I get the following error message:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.RestfulClient.sendPostRequest(RestfulClient.java:110)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.RestfulClient.send(RestfulClient.java:58)
at com.kms.katalon.controller.WebServiceController.sendRequest(WebServiceController.java:107)
at com.kms.katalon.composer.webservice.parts.RestServicePart$4.run(RestServicePart.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

I don't find anything wrong with the request and it is working fine when using Katalon 5.8.7.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Katalon Studio v**5.10.0**.